# cannot open pdf streamed by dompdf, help me

Tags: php, html, pdf, ckeditor, dompdf

I use ckeditor and dompdf for create pdf file, when I save it successfull create a pdf file but file can not be open. It's written 'failed to load pdf document'

I use dompdf version 0.6.1

```
require_once("converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html = "<html><body>".$_POST['editor']."</body></html>";
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("A4");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('file_'.$user.'.pdf');
```

Comment: Any errors (from PHP or your PDF viewer)? The most typical issue is that some non-PDF content (e.g. PHP notices) were caught in the PDF stream. So the PDF may be ok once you quiet the notices (recommend setting display_errors to off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) with php . easy

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.

As of you are using Dompdf i would rather suggest you that you can tcpdf for the same and it is very much easy to under stand and use. Beside that you can easily download the tcpdf from google. Below i am giving you the link for the same that how to create the pdf file using tcpdf. And additional you can also download the tcpdf from this link only.

Please visit [this](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps)

Hope this might be useful to you and solve your bugs !!

Waiting for your valuable comments !!!

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your suggestion, actually my issue already correct. Now I can open pdf file correctly but I will try your suggestion, hope it's will be better. Sorry for my bad english :)